# Made up in my mind

Tags: phrase-meaning

Do you use "made up" or "made" in such context or is there a better phrase to use?

"Sometimes horrible pictures are made up in my mind."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think either works very well in this case. The phrase "made up" can mean several different things, but none of those meanings fit well here.  And "made" doesn't work at all. Better options include:

> Sometimes I picture horrible scenes in my mind.

Or, if the "in my mind" seems a bit redundant:

> Sometimes I picture horrible scenes.

Or:

> Sometimes, in my head, I imagine horrible scenes.